# php array displaying in advance form

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array

```
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');
```

i want to display like this :

first line : `first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth,eleventh,twelvelveth,thirteenth`

second line : `second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth,eleventh,twelvelveth,thirteenth,first`

third line : `third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth,eleventh,twelvelveth,thirteenth,first,second`

fourth line : `fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth,eleventh,twelvelveth,thirteenth,first,second,third`

and so on dynamically.

when i add value or delete values on main array. the output also should be change.

Comment: How many lines are there supposed to be in your output? Your example has four, but there are thirteen items in your array. Shuld the output be thirteen lines long?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

```
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');
print_r($list);
$new = array_shift($list);
$list[] = $new;
print_r($list);
```

EDIT: (this displays it working through the array quite nicely)

```
<?
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');


for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++) {
    echo "---- $i ---- <br /><br />";
    print_r($list)."<br />"; 
    $new = array_shift($list);
    $list[] = $new;
    echo "<br /><br />";
    print_r($list); 
    echo "<br />";
    echo "----------- <br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This wuill work for you
<?php
//list the array
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');

//get the count
$count = count($list);

$val = '';
//loop the value
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    //skip one value
    $pop = array_shift($list);

    //appentd the value
    $val .= $pop.',';

    //display the value
    echo implode(',', $list).','.substr($val, 0, -1).'<br/>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it , this one of them

```
<?php
//array
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');
// array counter
$i=0;
// for loop max
$max = sizeof($list);

while(sizeof($list) != 0)
{   //for loop to echo data
    for($l=$i;$l<$max;$l++){
    echo $list[$l];
    // condition to not put comma after last number
    if($l != $max-1){echo ',';}
            }
// new line
echo '<br>';
// remove first element
unset($list[$i]);
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list=array('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth','eleventh','twelvelveth','thirteenth');

for( $i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {

    for($j = $i; $j < count($list); $j++) {
        echo $list[$j];
    }

    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
        echo $list[$j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

shift() will remove the first entry of the array :
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-shift.php

EDIT:
you edited so do I.

```
print_r($list);
$tmp = array_shift($list);
$list[] = $tmp;
print_r($list);
```

Comment: The item should not be removed but should be pushed to the back.

Comment: I think it should be something like `$list[] = array_shift($list);`

Comment: Is `shift` actually a method that can be called like this?